# How to access tmux session created in an ssh session locally?

Tags: tmux

After I created a tmux session and detached in an ssh session, running `tmux  attach` at a local terminal does not bring me the session I created (`tmux ls` also lists nothing). ps shows tmux is still running. How can I access it locally?

`ps auwx | grep tmux` shows

```
me      8404  0.0  0.0  28268  3900 ?        Ss   Jul13   0:15 tmux
```

Comment: Are you definitely logged in as the user that owns the tmux server?  Can you add a `ps auwx | grep tmux` to the question?

Comment: @Paul Yes. I've updated the question.

Comment: Cool - can you do `ps auwxf | grep -A1 tmux` to see if there are any child processes?

Comment: @Paul It has a subprocess zsh.

Comment: Ok great.  Are you in a GUI when using it locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The likely scenario here is that tmux via ssh was using a different TMPDIR when in ssh to that when you are local.  You can do this to see what it is set to:

```
echo $TMPDIR
```

Usually with ssh, it is not set to anything, and so uses /tmp.  You can try

```
TMPDIR=/tmp/ tmux attach
```

This will tell tmux to look in /tmp for its sockets.

If this doesn't work, they may be elsewhere, or been cleaned. In which case, you can tell tmux to recreate them:

```
killall -10 tmux
```

The `-10` signal tell tmux to recreate the sockets, it isn't a signal to terminate. You may need to do an ssh session to figure out where they get created by examining `TMPDIR` but most likely it is `/tmp/`.

Comment: Indeed the `TMPDIR` has messed things up. I don't have `TMPDIR` set locally but in an ssh session it is `/tmp/username`.